# NotImplementError:NotImplementError when perform a job in Rails and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob

When I perform my active job with sidekiq I receive NotImplementError, my job do a change of state of is_expired when expireDate == Date.today, I have this table:

```
class CreateRifas < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :rifas do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :rifDate
      t.date :expireDate
      t.string :plate
      t.integer :year
      t.float :price
      t.integer :numbers
      t.boolean :is_expired, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is my active job:

```
class ExpireRifJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform_later(rif_id)
    Rifa.find(rif_id).update(is_expired: true)
  end
end
```

And I call it through my controller Rifs_controller.rb with the method rifs#create

```
def create
  @rifa = Rifa.new(rif_params)
  if @rifa.save
    render json: @rifa, status: :created
    ExpireRifJob.set(wait_until: @rifa.expireDate).perform_later(@rif.id)
  else
    render json: { errors: @rif.errors.full_messages },
           status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

and I get this error from Sidekiq Web

[image: Error]

**Pd: When I change queue from default to critical, my job wait for ever when I set my work with a lifecycle of 10 seconds, my job wait for ever on queue list, my job is the first of the list and it doesn't execute though**

Log Error:

```
2022-08-20T16:29:26.891Z pid=11213 tid=1hd class=ExpireRifJob jid=3f4639bba336079df2b913dc INFO: Performing ExpireRifJob (Job ID: 302814a4-928f-4998-881a-c4d7f78cfce9) from Sidekiq(default) enqueued at 2022-08-20T16:29:11Z with arguments: 1
2022-08-20T16:29:26.891Z pid=11213 tid=1hd class=ExpireRifJob jid=3f4639bba336079df2b913dc ERROR: Error performing ExpireRifJob (Job ID: 302814a4-928f-4998-881a-c4d7f78cfce9) from Sidekiq(default) in 0.52ms: NotImplementedError (NotImplementedError):
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:52:in `perform'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:59:in `block in _perform_job'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/i18n-1.12.0/lib/i18n.rb:322:in `with_locale'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/translation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:66:in `use_zone'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/timezones.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Timezones>'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:58:in `_perform_job'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:20:in `_perform_job'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:46:in `perform_now'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `block in perform_now'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:25:in `block in instrument'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:35:in `instrument'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `perform_now'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:18:in `block in perform_now'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:114:in `block in tagged'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:38:in `tagged'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:114:in `tagged'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:25:in `tag_logger'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:18:in `perform_now'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:24:in `block in execute'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:54:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `block in wrap'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:88:in `wrap'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:71:in `wrap'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:22:in `execute'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activejob-7.0.3.1/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/sidekiq_adapter.rb:42:in `perform'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:196:in `execute_job'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:139:in `invoke'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:163:in `block in process'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:136:in `block (6 levels) in dispatch'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:115:in `local'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:135:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:14:in `block in call'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `block in wrap'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:71:in `wrap'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:13:in `call'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:257:in `stats'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:13:in `call'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:82:in `global'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:124:in `block in dispatch'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:39:in `prepare'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:123:in `dispatch'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:162:in `process'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:78:in `process_one'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/component.rb:8:in `watchdog'
/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/sidekiq-6.5.1/lib/sidekiq/component.rb:17:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Comment: `NotImplementError` indicates that a method you are calling does not exist. Please share the full error message and the stacktrace which you should find in the log file of your application. With that information, we can only guess what might be missing.

Comment: Sidenote: Your camelcase column names in the database and therefore your model attributes do not follow Ruby and Rails conventions. I suggest fixing that because it can lead to unexpected issues.

Comment: Can you try `.set(wait_until: 10.seconds.from_now)`?

Comment: where did you set ```@rifa.expireDate``` up when defining the rif expired ?

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh, I just noticed, you defined `perform_later` in your job, you have to define `perform`

Comment: i changed it and my job just stay enqueued and never change status of expireDate

Comment: The same job?  Did you try manually retrying it?

Comment: I did it, I was trying to set manually in the queue but the job only wait forever... i don't know what to do

Comment: I mean, just to confirm, you have deployed the change to your sidekiq server, right?  And restarted sidekiq?  Did you try deleting that job and creating another one?

Comment: i did it and nothing happens, I restart my sidekiq, I checked my queues and I create another job and I get same error

Comment: Makes no sense because literally an empty `NotImplementedError` is [what ActiveJob does](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activejob/lib/active_job/execution.rb#L52) when you don't define a `perform`.  All other places it has arguments.

Comment: I resign with this error, but to do the same function I will use a trigger in my table when expired = current date